# Polygon to line with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, line, polygon, svg-animate

I'm trying to achieve [this kind of effect](http://www.subaru.com/csr/environment.html)

I'm doing it with an SVG path where the distances of the nodes approach to 10,0 in order to get a straight line, but is not smooth. Is there a library to achieve that or another suggestion of how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see an example of your current working version?

Comment: we don't have enough code, but you should give http://mojs.io a try

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kqdxzuLp/ This is an example, I stopped working on that because this issue. At the moment the approach is not to 10,0, is only increasing or decrementing the amount in the zoom in. The zoom out doesn't work already. I don't want the approach with the scroll for desktops, I'm doing it with the keyboard. For mobile devices I will use HammerJS and pinch gesture.